# Shell Script - responder entrada de dados do terminal

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, shell-script

Galera, comecei a mexer com Shell Script para conseguir automatizar algumas tarefas no meu linux, e surgiu um dúvida. É possível responder a uma solicitação de entrada de dados feita pelo terminal através de um script desses? Minha ideia geral é automatizar o processo de commits e pushs do git. Porém, no caso do push, preciso inserir meu usuário e senha do git e queria fazer isso de forma automática através do script. É possível?
Meu código até aqui:

```
read -p "Digite a mensagem de commit: " MENSAGEM

if [ -n "$MENSAGEM" ];
then
    git add .
    git commit -m "$MENSAGEM"
else
    echo "ERRO: mensagem de commit vazia"
fi
```

Comment: Pode [associar uma chave SSH à sua conta do GitHub](https://github.com/settings/keys) e a autenticação passa a ser automática.

Comment: Pode automatizar  usando os recursos da propria api do github, pode facilitar ainda mais.acho que tem um limite de requisição por dia. bem mais simples do que refazer os comandos via shell e precisar do login e senha. https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/guides/basics-of-authentication

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Tenho algumas alternativas para o seu problema***

#### **1.Usar uma chave SSH**

chaves ssh sao geradas em seu computador e vinculadas a sua conta github para evitar usar usuario e senha, [veja aqui](https://mateusmuller.me/2019/09/25/como-configurar-o-github-para-nao-pedir-senha-a-cada-push/)

#### **2. Configurar o git em seu computador**

***ATENÇAO:*** Este método salva as credenciais em texto simples no disco do seu PC. Todos em seu computador podem acessá-lo, por exemplo, módulos NPM maliciosos.

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

eu nao estudei isso, so achei na internet :)

#### **3. Automatizar por shellscript**

essa e a resposta que voce estava procurando, acredito que ajude

```
(sleep 3; echo "usuario"; sleep 3; echo "senha";) | git push
```

basicamente antes do comando que voce quer responder deve ter um "**|**", o comando **sleep 3** faz o programa esperar 3 segundos antes de responder no terminal oque esta no **echo ""**

talvez a ordem de resposta nao esteja certa, mas isso é com vc

Boa Sorte :)